# data from mysql to highchart waterfall chart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have my website that initially loads with 3 dropdowns a table and a waterfall chart from highcharts. What I want is for the chart and table to dynamically change based on the dropdown selections that will then query the database which is MySQL.

The dropdowns trigger an onchange event that an jquery ajax event then uses my php script to query sql. My issue is, in the first instance the json is returning but i am struggling to utilise this data for the highchart waterfall chart demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/waterfall/

I am in no way an experienced coder, I have put this together by reading these forums and buying a few O'Reilly JS, PHP, MySQL books - unfortunately these books dont have the solution that I feel I'm looking for.

Would someone be kind enough to help me please and hopefully point me in the right direction, I am happy to learn not necessarily looking for someone to code this for me. I not sure that I completely understand how ajax/jquery/json -> PHP actually work - this may be part of the problem.

php code - extractData.php:

```
<?php

require('dB_connect.php');

//$reportID = $_POST['weeknumber'].''.$_POST['year'];

$reportID = intval($_GET['q']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `flashreport` WHERE ID = '".$reportID."'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

$emparray = array();
   while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    $emparray[] = $row;
  }
echo stripslashes(json_encode($emparray));

mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

the jquery code - report.html:

```
<script>
var week = "";
var year = "";
var both = "";
$(function weekNumDate() {
  $('#weeknumber').on('change', function () {
  if($(this).val() == 0) {
     week = "";
  } else {
      week = $(this).val();
      year = $('#year').val();
      both = week + year
  }
  dateId(both);
  return false;
});

$('#year').on('change', function () {
  if($(this).val() == 0) {
     year = "";
  } else {
     year = $(this).val();
     week = $('#weeknumber').val();
     both = week + year
  }
 dateId(both);
 return false;
  });
});

function dateId(str) {
$.getJSON('extractData.php', 'id=str', function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("div").append(field + " ");
    });
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Could you perty please provide an example of the raw json returned from the call to `extractData.php` and an example of the json created at the end of the `$.each()` loop. thanks!

Comment: For the waterfall example you have provided, you will have to get the data from the PHP in a JSON format similar to what that graph expects. Then once you get the AJAX response, you can initiate the Highchart for any specific container (using id or class in query). I hope this helps

Comment: [{"ID":"22016","NMECH":"3.00","NELECT":"3.00","NCIVIL":"55.00","NPLANT":"0.00","CMECH":"0.00","CELECT":"0.00","CCIVIL":"0.00","CPLANT":"0.00","SMECH":"0.00","SELECT":"0.00","SCIVIL":"0.00","SPLANT":"0.00","NPJOB":"22","CBREAKHRS":"0","C3RDHRS":"0","CLOSTHRS":"0","CACTHRS":"0","COVERTIMEHRS":"0","SBASEHRS":"0","SABHRS":"0","SAVAILHRS":"0","SREACTHRS":"0","SBREAKHRS":"0","S3RDHRS":"0","SLOSTHRS":"0","SACTHRS":"0","SOVERTIMEHRS":"0"}]

Comment: This json was produced not by a jquery ajax but by a javascript ajax call. How would I use this to dynamically change the waterfall chart? Would the chart be placed in the php script or the html page?

Comment: are property names, e.g. NMECH, NELECT, etc your "x" axis and the property values, e.g. 3.00, 55.00, 0.00, etc your "y" axis values?

Comment: The values that will make up the waterfall chart is cbreakhrs, c3rdhrs,closthrs,cacthrs,covertimehrs - these are indeed 'x' axis

Comment: Could anyone give me a good example that could help me please?

Comment: @KevinSullivan please study this: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<waterfall>.data and determine how your data should be formatted, and either provide a more detailed explanation of the data your are attempting to chart and/or provide an example of the data in a json format, according to the specifics provided by the documentation link. thanks.

Comment: @KevinSullivan maybe this fiddle, using what little I know of the datasets, will help provide some inspiration: https://jsfiddle.net/sunoterra/afps5ohv/

Comment: @MichaelStilson thank you for the try, its exceptionally good considering you haven't a huge amount of info to go on. My jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kevinsullivan10/8hg7h2eu/

Comment: what i am struggling with is how to capture that data from the Db turn it into json and then use the data dynamically when the dropdown value changes from say week 1 to week 2.

Comment: @KevinSullivan yeah, getting the data in the correct format sometimes is most of the challenge. :) well my advice, try not to think about changing weeks at the moment, and just focus on getting a correct format for one week. once that's complete, making the jump to changing those weeks based on date range selection may come into a clearer view.

Comment: how could you incorporate isIntermediateSum: true, within the data series in the chart. Are you able to get each of the json values in their own variables and then call them in the chart directly?

Comment: @KevinSullivan hey, if you got some time to collab on fiddle, jump on the one that you put up.

Comment: @MichaelStilson - Hi, would be happy to collab with you, you appear to be extremely knowledgeable, however - not sure how you collaborate on jsfiddle?

Comment: @KevinSullivan it maybe too late your time, but if not: https://jsfiddle.net/kevinsullivan10/8hg7h2eu/#&togetherjs=wAezG60VPV